# How do I use 7-zip command line in vb script to delete file from zip folder?

Tags: vbscript

I have this vb script:

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Run the 7-zip command line instruction via thw WshShell to delete files in Tableau Export Packaged Workbook
desfile = "C:\Tableau_Dashboards\Partner_Life_Cycle\ALL_PARTNERS\twbx\Partner_Life_Cycle_ALL_PARTNERS.zip"
srfile = "C:\Tableau_Dashboards\Partner_Life_Cycle\ALL_PARTNERS\twbx\Data"
strCommand = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe d -tzip   & desfile & srfile & "

' Run 7-Zip in shell
WshShell.Run strCommand,0,true
WScript.Sleep 5000
```

I get the error "Line 15: The system cannot find the file specified"

Line 15 is the WshShell.Run strCommand,0,true part.

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Rick

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the concatenation operator `&` will be treated as a part of the string since you are not closing the previous string with a  quote.

It should be:

`strCommand = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe d -tzip" & " " & desfile & " " & srfile`

(With space added  between the paths.)

As the path to the exe contains space (*Program Files*), it will have to be enclosed in quotes as: "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

To get a quote within a string in vbscript, the quote has to be doubled .

`strCommand = """C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"" d -tzip" & " " & desfile & " " & srfile`